# using javascript in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to start an activity from a javascript interface in my webview.
The example shows a toast. How could i call a class instead of a toast?

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

this for the html page.

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
}
```

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to answer but have you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript

Comment: Ok I just didn't see anywhere where you enabled the javascript in the webview and though it was relevant.

Comment: u didnt get my question , i want to call an intent instead of a toast . i already made that toasts example working. thx anyway

Comment: I want to do it without any webview . just internally is it possible.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have to first register the JavaScriptInterface on your webview.
JavaScriptInterFace can be a inner class as shown below. This class will have a function that you can call from html page( via javaScript ) and inside this function you can write code to change activity.

Here is the working solution for you:

```
public class JavascriptInterfaceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    WebView wv;

    JavaScriptInterface JSInterface;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // register class containing methods to be exposed to JavaScript

        JSInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "JSInterface"); 

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myPage.html");

    }


    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public void changeActivity()
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(JavascriptInterfaceActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the html page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage()
{
JSInterface.changeActivity();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you my friend . it almost helped me to solve my problem .

Comment: @Common i should take the above html code in separate html file ?

Comment: This is useful to call android functions from a javascript, but there is any way to call javascript functions from android code?

Comment: what is the location of this html file ?

Comment: @Tony_craft You should use something like webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Hello!')");

Comment: I have one question, where to put the HTML page ?

Comment: @Suda.nese Wherever in the `assets` folder

Comment: I using your Activity Class in my project but I have a problem, I can't change to the second activity. My post is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572948/android-how-to-use-javascript-in-an-android-webview?noredirect=1#comment86156934_49572948

Comment: Great solution. Does anyone know if this is a valid solution for iOS too?

Answer (score 18):

You also need to add the **@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface** annotation on top of your `changeActivity` method in your android code, should you run on Android 4.2 or higher.
See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031635/android-4-2-1-webview-and-javascript-interface-breaks) for more.