# Webview client not Listening shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, webview

In my application there is a Login screen at the very first time which shows in a web view. In that screen a pop up will appear which has UserName and Password. After giving the details when the Log in button is pressed the UserName and password is submitted and a it will call a php code for username and password validation which redirects to a link which will reload in the webview. When this URL is loaded I have to listen the URL and if the URL matches some consideration i want to finish the webview activity and move on to next activity.

The problem is as when I cant Listen the URL that generates after the login. As the Login button does not have a login, shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not calling. I tried using onPageFinished, onLoadResource, onPageStarted. But only few devices calling these function.

I want to get the URL after the Login button is pressed. Is there any other way to solve this problem.

This is my code:

```
public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
WebView mWebView;
Context ctx;
String str = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ctx = this;

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                android.webkit.JsResult result) {
            // Required functionality here
            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://This is my log in screen");


}

class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    MyWebClient() {
        Log.e("test", "Inside WebViewClient");
    }

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Log.e("onPageStarted", url);
        str = str + "onPageStarted : " + url + "\n";
    }

    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.e("onLoadResource", url);
        str = str + "onLoadResource : " + url + "\n";
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.e("onPageFinished", url);
        str = str + "onPageFinished : " + url + "\n";
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        str = str + "shouldOverrideUrlLoading : " + url + "\n";
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

Thanks Regards,
Sniper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the login screen html page and if you can change it then
i will suggest you to use javaScriptInterface to handle onClickListener of your login button.

link below shows the way to use javascriptInterface to get html button click and call android function from that clickEvent.

[using javascript in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview/10481108#10481108)

hope this helped you...

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my time. But after finishing the activity a dialog is showing "complete action using Dialog" with the list of browsers in the device. How can i avoid it.