# How to embed some info into http request in Android?

Tags: android, tcp, http-headers

Is there a way to access device information via the browser? Information such as Battery status, Wifi status, 3g status, etc? Is there any way to get the android browser to give this information via an http request?

Comment: I dont think there are any apis that allow for this yet. Mozilla is working on something called WebAPI but thats about it.

Comment: Ok, what about embedding such info. at the tcp level? say in the options field. is there a way that the (browser/or the OS) can read the status of: (1) battery status, (2) network type a smartphone is using (3G, WiFi, etc? and then embed it in the options field?

Comment: The only way to do this in android is to build a custom application using Webview. Somelike like PhoneGap will do this for you. (phonegap provides you with a "platform independent"-ish api so you could deploy to ios or windows phone too). All options require you to deploy a custom application that your users' would use.

Comment: Thanks @ techsaint. On the other side I want to have a web server that can deliver different web pages to my mobile client based on certain criteria. Is that possible?

Comment: Yep @user173449 , It is very possible to use javascript to detect the device information and pass that information on with a server request. Then you can use that information server-side to redirect the user to whatever content you want. depending on how acurate you want the redirects to be, you can always use user-agent to tell what browser a user has when they are accessing your server link. With useragent you wont need to deploy anything client side for that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get Device information via browser, but your browser need support JavascriptInterface. If your browser supported JavascriptInterface then you can call method of activity in javascript code.

First read this and you can know how to use JavascriptInterface in WebView:

- [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)
- [using javascript in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview)
- [Android Development:JavaScript Bridge Example – Fully Explained!](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/03/16/android-development-javascript-bridge-example-fully-explained/)