# enable voice/audio over ip webcam android

Tags: android, webview, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, ip-camera

Currently I am using webview to project display from one android to another and its working fine but I cannot listen to any audio/voice .I dont know how to make it work in android.Can we ambed vlc in android in custom android app or any other app like ustream anything would do.Basically I want video/audio from one android phone to another .How do I do that ??

Using this app on client : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en

Unable to listen to audio on Server.

Please help me out ?? I am stuck after googling for many days and only ip stream with video and on wifi is working on 3g it lags a lot .

I really appreciate the help to guide/inspire/motivate to any direction where I can implement the above requirements.

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm curious how you did that with the web views alone. Repo or code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview url will be the ip its hosting on .THe video is perfect but no audio it requires browser audio I dont know how to enable that in android webview.Same works perfectly on chrome/firefox desktop browser.

Comment: I know this is leading to a discussion, but that shows how to run android code in a browser using JS. The thing I'm asking is about discovery of the other device, transferring of packets across the network and such.

Comment: the software ipwebcam generates the ip and I have to load it into a browser with the specific link and it streams the video.You can download the app I have mentioned above and check it out.Or you can suggest me something better if you have come across any.Thank You Sir for your time.

Comment: Oh ok, now I get what you are doing. I'll add an answer to for the audio.

Answer (score 0):

## Write to a Socket.

One thing, you could do is to get the `AudioRecorder` class to stream to a `LocalSocket`. This way as and when you have bytes flowing in from the `AudioRecorder`, they're pushed to `LocalSocket`.

Can someone improve upon my answer, I've just seen this done before, never really tried it myself.

PS: The class names here are from memory, might be a little off on that.

Comment: Okay I found two links for the steaming app: 1.for Videofeed :URL for MJPG compataible and 2.Audio : /audio.ogg .I am thinking can I use both the links and display audio/video steam on my android app ??

Comment: Another query does video by defination include audio or just the display ??? I have come across this the first time.Sorry Sir.

Comment: If you think, you can get them to play in parallel without going out of sync (which is hard when done separately) you can do what you said in comment #1. 
Video by definition just means the visual part, but in regular usage audio is also expected. If you were referring to MJPG above, it is just the visual part.