# Is it possible to trigger android back button default function using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Experts,

I've been searching all day for this, but I could not find one!

Is it possible to trigger android back button programmatically using `javascript/jquery` (other than cordova) ? 
Currently I am developing a cross-platform application that is not `cordova-capable` on this particular page. Thus, I am relying on `javascript/jquery` only.

Comment: Are you using webview?

Comment: @WaqarKhan i am.. its html5 based

Comment: First you have to Override `onBackPressed()`. Then you have to implement `JavaScriptInterface` in your activity. And call the `onBackPressed()` method from `JavaScriptInterface` This is well descirbed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22897061/3117296)

Comment: @WaqarKhan Thanks! but i dont have control to that android activity class. Instead, i am now on an HTML page without cordova capabilities. I am looking for javascript or jquery to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @WaqarKhan iam afraid that it wont help. It is just a .html page. The android backbutton could navigate me to the previous page i visited, however history.back() or history.go(-1) could not.