# How can I use text from a website in a TextView?

Tags: android

I'm very new to android development. I'm simply trying to grab text from a website (let's say it's called `http://foo.com/meg_message`) and use this text to fill a TextView. What is the best way to do this?

I have the following XML element:

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/meg_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            tools:text=""/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you mean by grab text from a website? you mean once you call that url you will get a message response?

Comment: Show us the code you made so far.

Answer (score 2):

If your `http://foo.com/meg_message` returns a response when you call it ,

In manifest use internet permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Get you response like this

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(yourURL);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {                    
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String result = sb.toString();
            Log.v("Response : ", result);
```

`yourURL` example :http://foo.com/meg_message

Now ready a `textView`

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_id);
tv.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is your own website you can call javascript method to invoke your java native methord and fill whatever required. Please refer this answer for more info

[Call Android methods from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895140/call-android-methods-from-javascript)