# Is there any function to detect if video is finished with webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am setting up a webview component that loads a youtube URL . I can play videos but I want to detect if the user has really watched the video or not? Is there any way to do this. The video can also be from other sites than youtube.

Comment: I don't think you can check if the video in webview is finished or not.
Although you can use a `Handler` and after a certain time, can do whatever you want to do.

Comment: You can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895140/call-android-methods-from-javascript.