# get output of javascript on android

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have this javascript code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
document.write("my number is "+ i );
}
</script>

</head>

</html>
```

I want to take the output of this javascript code and save in String in android.
like this:

`my number is 0my number is 1my number is 2my number is 3my number is 4my number is 5`

How can i do this in android?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lof of topic already opened/answered for this question.

Check these links

[using javascript in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview)

[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

Basic is binding your WebView injecting a javascript into the webpage, then you can call your java function in webpage with normal javascript.

Comment: i dont want to use webview,
i want to get output of javascript in my String object in android

Comment: how do you think to execute javascript without a WebView? (if i understood correctly what you need)