# How to transfer complex objects from Java to JS in Android WebView?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, uiwebview

IOS platform supports this kind of feature, but not Android.

Supported types for i-os UIWebView are described under the following URLs

[Using JavaScript From Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html)

[Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is adding a JavaScriptInterface to the WebView, this allows you to get results from JavaScript in your Java code, and you can send data to JavaScript by just loading a script in WebView. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview

Comment: This Javascript interface mentioned by you allows only to transfer primitive data types and Strings Of course String could be used for JSON, but I need the same for complex types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in fact return other Java objects, not only primitive types from methods of injected objects. Consider this simplified example:

Java:

```
class MyObject {
    class Transport {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public int getField() { ... }
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public Object getTransport() { return new Transport(); }
}

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyObject(), "myObject");
```

JavaScript:

```
{
    ...
    var transport = myObject.getTransport();
    return transport.getField();
}
```

Java and JavaScript objects live on different heaps, so you have to copy the data over anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would be nice to have a way to transfer byte arrays at least without converting them to String.

Comment: Sorry, currently arrays can only be passed from JS to Java, not the other way round. Passing as a JSON string and then parsing it on the JS side with `JSON.parse` will probably be the fastest way to pass an array from Java to JS.