# Is it Possible to pass parameters from Web View to My Application?

Tags: android, webview, server

I have a Web site.. I am Using that website In my web view with user credentials in that if user want to take print 
on server side it is done on click it will find network printer and it will print.
all this possible In webview..

But,
In the same way if he want to take print from Bluetooth or Usb.

is it possible to pass perimeters form **Web-view to my Application**..

So that User can Print their own data..

Here I have done with Integrating Printer sdk and Specific user..
Please suggest me, any solution or example.. here If I give code its too complected.and so Huge..

so I am asking is it possible to pass perimeters form **`Server or Web-View`** to my application. depending on logged device...

**Update**

Here It may be from Website or web-view.. from another location....

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

By using Javascript, for instance, you can have a function to gather device information, then serialize it and finaly add it to the form.

[Check an JavascriptInterface example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview)