# Application terminates while using document.location

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am using android studio and trying to make a mobile app using JavaScript.

I have already loaded `index.html` using webview.
Now I want go to `ShoppingList.html` which is saved in `assets` using the following JavaScript code.

When I use the emulator with android version 6 it works perfectly. But with android version 7 my application terminates when the `Navigate()` function is called.

I also tried `window.location`and `document.location.href` but nothing works.

The JavaScript code I'm using to navigate to another html file is:

```
function Navigate()
{
    document.location = "file:///android_asset/www/ShoppingList.html";
}
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is with permissions to read a file from FS. Review permissions, please, and make sure file exists.

Comment: `my application terminates` these messages do not fly here. Post the **actual stacktrace / error**

Comment: This is what I have got from my error log:

     05-16 17:13:01.247 9294-9294/com.stephaniemartin.kitchentool 
     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
     Process: com.stephaniemartin.kitchentool, PID: 9294
                                                                        
     android.os.FileUriExposedException: 
     file:///android_assets/www/ShoppingList.html exposed beyond app 
     through Intent.getData()

Answer (score 0):

Putting your web resources into the assets folder, you can call webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html").
For Complete Communication between Java and Webview [See this](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-webview-loading-custom-html-and.html)
and maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview)