# Embedding PowerBI report with an iOS app developed in Xcode

Tags: xcode, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a simple PowerBI report with 2-3 visualizations that uses Azure database to get data. I want to see how I can embed this report in an iOS app that we are working on. We're using Xcode for developing the app. I want that report to be accessible using our own in-house app and not PowerBI app.

In my Xcode project I added a WebKit component and added the embedded code URL for the report. When I run the simulator, it asks me to sign in to PowerBI but if I click on the Sign-In link, it doesn't do anything. Is that the expected behavior?

I was wondering if anyone has worked on a solution like this before. Also, i thought if you use PowerBI embedding, it shouldn't ask the user to login. Is that correct? If not, what would be the best way to embed the report to the iOS app without asking the users to login?

Comment: Take a look at this question for list of things that you should do to embed a Power BI report in you app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878531/how-to-add-power-bi-reports-in-android-native-app-in-2019

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the best way to embed the report to the ios app without asking the users to login?

Follow the tutorial here:  [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers)

Your back-end app generates an embed token for the browser to use with the Javascript API to embed and interact with the report visual.