# How to embed a powerbi report within a flutter android application?

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart, powerbi

I'm creating an android application using flutter where I need to embed a powerbi report within the app itself. I could not find a single resource to aid me with this task. I've already created a web application where I've done the same. (Yes, I can create a webview, no I don't want a webView). Please help or point me to the correct resource for this.

Comment: PowerBI is a commercial product, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-app-ssrs-kpis-mobile-on-premises-reports, unless Microsoft provides a client SDK at best all you can do is read the data from a webserver and show your own tables, charts & graphs.

Comment: That link points to the original PowerBI application, I wanted to embed a report in my own application. How do I go about reading the data from a webserver and rendering it in my own application is my actual question!

Comment: That question is too broad for StackOverflow. You can break the problem down into smaller questions like 'how do I get data in Flutter from a web service' which you can easily find with a search engine. Once you have code and are stuck with a specific problem, after searching then post on StackOverflow with code and error. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Power BI reports in Android native app in 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878531/how-to-add-power-bi-reports-in-android-native-app-in-2019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem. As I've already created a web app, I added full screen reports in my react app itself, and used an inapp webView in flutter to display the reports using : https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview

Hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: so, let me get this straight... you created a website it react that renders the powerBi data, and then show that website in flutter using the inAppWebview flutter package?

Comment: @WilliamTerrill Yup