How can I get PageView behave like Apple TV app header?
I need to implement an exactly the same carousel like in Apple TV app with that kind of parallax effect.
The next page in Page view should start from the image's center on scroll and expanding to a full width when the next page is in center of a screen.
It should look like this
I was looking into dynamic change of viewportFraction on scroll but had no luck because it changes for all items in a PageView but not for individual ones.

Look at this, This will be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620300/13974685

How is that related to the issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Found a solution so if someone curious how to achieve such parallax effect, here's the code
    AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 0.66,
        child: PageView.builder(
        pageSnapping: false,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        controller: _pageController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items[index];

            return AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _pageController,
                builder: (context, child) {
                    double page = 0.0;

                    try {
                        page = _pageController.page!;
                    } catch (e) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }

                    double widthFactor = 1;
                    widthFactor = (1 - (index - page).abs()).abs();

                    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

                    return Align(
                        alignment: index > page
                            ? Alignment.centerLeft
                            : Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: SizedBox(
                        width: mediaQuery.size.width * widthFactor,
                        height: // *set the height of content here*,
                        child: child,
                    ),
                );
            },
            child: // *your content here*,
        );
    },
    onPageChanged: (value) {
       _currentIndex = value;
    },
),

),
