# How to change in-app language with WebView

Tags: android, webview

Currently developing an app. I'm using webview in the android app, so in my website i have 2 folders, one for each language, "pt & en".

Is possible in a single app to do that?

Comment: please show what you have done so far and where the problem is exactly.

Comment: You can register JavaScriptInterface on your WebView, please, check this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/10481108/341998

Answer (score 0):

Load the HTML based on language is the app/system language handle the page.

Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales.get(0)?.language //Get's the system language code